# To get Fault exception on client side

Tags: c#, wcf, faultexception

I am new to WCF and trying to build a demo WCF project with `WebHttpBinding` binding.

The projects work fine but I am stuck with concept of fault exception. Below is the code I am using to generate fault exception but on client side what I get is **(400) Bad Request** error and the InnerException is null. Where am I getting wrong?

```
    public DataTable GetCreativesData(string id,string type)
    {
        try { 
        DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
        string qryStr = @"select * from dbo.tbMyTable";
        if (type != null && type != "")
            qryStr += " WHERE1 type='"+type+"'";
        DataTable dt = da.GetDataTable(qryStr);
        return dt;
        }

       catch (FaultException ex) {
            throw new FaultException("Improper Query");
        }
     }
```

Comment: Are u throwing `FaultException` from your WCF service?

Comment: yes..i am raising it from WCF service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 400 error is correct for a fault exception, since you are indicating to the user that something is wrong likely with what they provided.

There is no inner exception when you raise the `FaultException`, since a core concept of `FaultException` is that it works across technologies (interoperability) & the concept of an inner exception is very specific to .NET.

If you really wanted to pass an `Exception` down, you could use the [FaultException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576199(v=vs.110).aspx) which allows you to specify a generic parameter and then you set that to `Exception`. You would then create and raise that.

Another aspect to remember is how you are handling your errors, in your code you are throwing a brand new exception. That means that all the information in the variable ex, is lost. Unless you intend to hide something, you could try this

```
catch (FaultException ex) 
{
    throw;
}
```

This option takes the original `FaultException` and raises it again, thus preserving all the information in it.

Lastly and outside your question, that SQL scares me - looks like it could be vulnerable to a [SQL injection attack](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) - just something you may want to check.

Comment: thank you for explanation Robert..but what if i have to show actual error to user....like suppose we have divide operation in service and if user pass number  0....then i would like to show custom message to user...and that SQL is just for local testing purpose..

Comment: Added information on FaultException<TDetail> which maybe what you want